# Kusto: How to filter Logs in a certian time period?

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I want to filter SignIn-Logs with **Kusto** whose timestamps are only between 6pm and 6am.

Something like that

```
SignInLogs
| where TimeGenerated between(dateStart .. dateEnd)
```

All examples I have found are always based on a full timestamp with exact date, like `(2014-05-25T08:20:03.123456Z)`. But I am only interested in the time.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Kusto: How to filter Logs in a certian time period?

- ***between operator*** - Filters a record set for data that falls within an inclusive range of values.
- between is used to allow a certain range, but you can also use **!between** to exclude a time range.
- Here Iam excluding from 6 am to 6 pm , so it gives the left over time range i.e.. from 6pm to 6 am

Try the below query

```cs
SignInLogs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| extend hour = datetime_part("hour", TimeGenerated)
| where hour !between (6 .. 18)
```

[image]